# Is there ever any reason for the number of indices to exceed the number of fields? (MySQL or RDBMS in general)?

Tags: database, indexing

Suppose you have a table with 2 fields, like first name and last name.

If you add a composite index on both fields, that should theoretically take care of indexing the first field. Creating a second index on that field is redundant, as far as I know. To make sure all queries use indexes, you would only have to add an index to last name.

So it seems that the number of indexes on a table should not be larger than the number of fields in a table.

Is that correct or not? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a table T with 3 index-worthy columns: A, B, C.

1. The primary index might be on T(A, B, C).
2. There might be queries for which A and C are defined, so the index for those is T(A, C).
3. There might be queries for which B is defined: T(B) is the index.
4. There might be queries for which C is defined: T(C) is the index.

That looks like more indexes than columns.

The more columns there are in the table, the easier it is to come up with possible indexes that might help — and might push the index count higher than the column count.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So, to decide on whether to add more composite indexes, I should presumably look at my WHERE clauses to see which ones use more than one field.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the criteria.  You also need to balance the space used to store the indexes, and the cost of maintaining those indexes, against the amount of use.  As a minor side effect, if there are more indexes to consider, it takes longer to optimize a query as there are more options to consider.  However, that is seldom really measurable, let alone significant.